# Email text has incorrect default encoding in client program

Tags: perl, email, encoding, smtp

I am trying to send an email containing Russian text and subject in utf-8 encoding. Email is being received, when I open it in the web interface of gmail, everything is correct. But when I open the email in "The bat" client, the encoding is incorrect by default (I can set it manually to utf-8 though):

```
Subject: "Hello. РўРµРєСЃС‚"
Body: "test email. Р СѓСЃСЃРєРёР№ С‚РµРєСЃС‚"
```

Instead of:

```
Subject: "Hello. Текст"
Body: "test email. Русский текст"
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP ();
use Email::Simple ();
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

sub send_email
{
    my $email_from = shift;
    my $email_to = shift;
    my $subject = shift;
    my $message = shift;

    my $smtpserver = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    my $smtpport = 465;
    my $smtpuser   = 'user@gmail.com';
    my $password = 'secret';

    my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
        host => $smtpserver,
        port => $smtpport,
        sasl_username => $smtpuser,
        sasl_password => $password,
        debug    => 1,
        ssl => 1,
    });

    my $email = Email::Simple->create(
        header => [
            To      => $email_to,
            From    => $email_from,
            Subject => $subject,
        ],
        body => $message,
    );

    $email->header_set( 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' );
    $email->header_set( 'charset' => 'UTF-8' );
    sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
}

my $body = Encode::encode('utf-8', 'test email. Русский текст');
my $subject = Encode::encode('utf-8', 'Hello. Текст');
send_email('user@gmail.com', 'user@gmail.com', $subject, $body);
```

How to tell the email clients that the encoding is utf-8?

Comment: did you try send message with utf-8 by google web interface and open it by "the bat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Give `Email::Sender`/`Net::SMTP` string of bytes

`Email::Sender` (`Net::SMTP`) expects bytes ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251617/2139766) mentioned by [user4035](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789186/user4035)):

```
my $msg = $email->as_string();
utf8::encode($msg) if utf8::is_utf8($msg);
sendmail($msg, ...);
```

### Email body encoding

Set all three MIME headers for "raw" utf-8 email body:
(You may use `text/html` instead of typical `text/plain`)

```
$email->header_set( 'MIME-Version' => '1.0' );
$email->header_set( 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' );
$email->header_set( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8bit');
```

Your SMTP server should accept it and conduct conversions from "raw" (8-bit) utf-8 to another email encoding **if necessary**.  Most modern email servers do it.
*See  [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) comment about notable exceptions among email providers [1&1 (GMX)].*

### Email headers encoding:

```
$email->header_raw_set( 'Subject' => Encode::encode('MIME-Header',$subject));
```

### Debug procedure

Create minimal `Email::Simple` message, print it on utf-8 terminal
(`print $email->as_string();`) and post the result.

Comment: "Calling encode('utf-8',...) before calling send_email is not necessary when you use use utf-8; " - it is necessary. Please, look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248458/perl-smtp-cant-send-email-with-non-ascii-characters-in-body

Comment: Setting `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` should only be done if the receiving MTA supports the 8BITMIME SMTP extension. Most do but some major mail provider like 1&1 (GMX) don't. Thus to be compatible the message should be sent with a Content-Transfer-Encoding of quoted-printable or base64.